# Where is `shared-du` (`reflink-tools`)?

Tags: linux, du, reflink

The OCFS2 manual page describing `reflink` snapshots describes a tool named `shared-du`, together with examples.
However I'm unable to locate that tool on the web.
Where can I find it?

Citing from the manual page:

```text
Enter shared-du(1), a shared extent-aware du. This utility reports the shared extents per file
in parenthesis and the overall footprint. As expected, it lists the overall footprint at 5GB.
One can view the details of the extents using shared-filefrag(1). Both these utilities are
available at http://oss.oracle.com/~smushran/reflink-tools/.
```

Of course the URL does not exist any more (It seems Oracle really hates OSS).

Comment: [\[Ocfs2-users\] where can i find shared-du and shared-filefrag ?](https://oss.oracle.com/pipermail/ocfs2-users/2019-August/006505.html)

Comment: The link points to https://github.com/markfasheh/ocfs2-tools, but the requested tools could not be found.